# Replace four letter word in python

Tags: python, replace, words

I am trying to write a program that opens a text document and replaces all four letter words with ****. I have been messing around with this program for multiple hours now. I can not seem to get anywhere. I was hoping someone would be able to help me out with this one. Here is what I have so far. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
def censor():
    filename = input("Enter name of file: ")
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    file1 = open(filename, 'w')
    for element in file:
        words = element.split()
        if len(words) == 4:
            file1 = element.replace(words, "xxxx")
            alist.append(bob)
        print (file)
    file.close()
```

here is revised verison, i don't know if this is much better

```
def censor():
    filename = input("Enter name of file: ")
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    file1 = open(filename, 'w')
    i = 0
    for element in file:
        words = element.split()
        for i in range(len(words)):
            if len(words[i]) == 4:
                file1 = element.replace(i, "xxxx")
                i = i+1
    file.close()
```

Comment: There really is no need to repeat yourself. If you have a query to do with a specific answer then write a comment. If new information has come to light then update your question. Repeating your question because you didn't understand the answers given is not cool. The people here will help you if you are willing to put in some thought

Comment: you dont know? What's that mean? If you dont know how for loops work then read this http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html. It will help.

Comment: If you understand how loops work then you would not be getting confused about how to deal with `element`, `words` and `word`. I think add in some print statements just to make sure you know what it all means... Also if you understood you wouldn't have had that extra `i=0`...

Answer (score 2):

```
for element in file:
    words = element.split()
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == 4:
            etc etc
```

Here's why:

say the first line in your file is 'hello, my name is john'
then for the first iteration of the loop: `element = 'hello, my name is john'`
and `words = ['hello,','my','name','is','john']`

You need to check what is inside each word thus `for word in words`

Also it might be worth noting that in your current method you do not pay any attention to punctuation. Note the first word in `words` above...

To get rid of punctuation rather say:

```
import string

blah blah blah ...
for word in words:
    cleaned_word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
    if len(cleaned_word) == 4:
       etc etc
```

Comment: thanks for the help. How would i target just one word then? instead of the whole sentence

Comment: `for word in words:` please read the code I included. This is in the first sample

Comment: i did some changes, i posted it up above since i couldn't get it to post down here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: `len(words)` returns the number of words on the current line, not the length of any particular word. You need to add code that would look at every word on your line and decide whether it needs to be replaced.

Also, if the file is more complicated than a simple list of words (for example, if it contains punctuation characters that need to be preserved), it might be worth using a regular expression to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this:

```
def censor():
    filename = input("Enter name of file: ")
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    newLines = []
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if len(word) == 4:
                words[i] == '**'
        newLines.append(' '.join(words))

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for line in newLines:
            f.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(filename):
"""Takes a file and writes it into file censored.txt with every 4-letterword replaced by xxxx"""
infile = open(filename)
content = infile.read()
infile.close()
outfile = open('censored.txt', 'w')
table = content.maketrans('.,;:!?', '      ')
noPunc = content.translate(table) #replace all punctuation marks with blanks, so they won't tie two words together
wordList = noPunc.split(' ')
for word in wordList:
    if '\n' in word:
        count = word.count('\n')
        wordLen = len(word)-count
    else:
        wordLen = len(word)
    if wordLen == 4:
        censoredWord = word.replace(word, 'xxxx ')
        outfile.write(censoredWord)
    else:
        outfile.write(word + ' ')
outfile.close()
```

Comment: How does this answer the question, provide an explanation. Read the SO guidelines before posting.