# How to open a file to write to, write new information, and then close the file?

Tags: python, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace four letter word in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284291/replace-four-letter-word-in-python)

I want write a file in the python shell, run a program in it, and then close the file.

Here is the code I have right now.

```
def censor(fileName):
    file = open(fileName, "r")
    for i in len(myList):
        censoredFile = open("censored.txt", "w")
        outputFile.write(censoredFile)
    outputFile.close()
```

The program I want to run isn't in the program yet because I'm just trying to figure out how to deal with files. I have some programming experience but not a lot with files. Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by "run a program in it"?

Comment: I mean, eventually I want to run a program that will take a set of characters in the file, and replace them with a set of different set of characters every time a 4 letter word shows up. But right now I'm just trying to figure out how to deal with files.

Comment: I'll try to post the answer than. So, you need to open the file, read its contents, replace every four letter word with a different set of characters and than write the final result into another file. Is that it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284291/replace-four-letter-word-in-python/13284356#13284356 lol

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: So you made a new user profile so you could repeat your question without being scolded?

Comment: It looks very much like you still dont understand how for loops work in python btw. Look it up, it will make your life much easier

Comment: @Sheena, more like everyone has the same programming assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you need to read a file, replace all the four letter word and write the final result into a different file.

```
def censor(fileName):
    output_content = ""
    with open(fileName, "r") as input_file:
        with open("censored.txt", "w") as output_file:
            output_content = ""
            for line in input_file:
                output_content += ' '.join([word if len(word) != 4 else "****" for word in line.split(" ")])
            output_file.write(output_content)
```

It should be it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying out the code right now.

Comment: hang on, there is a problem with the regex

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a similar problem. It edits out every single character that contains 4 or more words, and not just 4.

Comment: THANK YOU. That solved the problem. I'm going to go over some documentation and experiment with it a bit more, but this gives me a good understanding of it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(fileName):
    censoredFile = open("censored.txt", "w")
    for line in open(fileName, "r"):
        censoredLine= do_stuff_to_censor_line(line)
        censoredFile.write(censoredLine)
```

In plain english here is what the function does:

```
1. open the output file

2. go through the input file... for each line:
   2.1 figure out what the censored version of the line would be
   2.2 write the censored version of the line to the output file

3. close both files (this happens automatically so you dont actually have to call close()
```

Now for the actual censoring of a line... 
Just looking at 4 letter words is probably not powerful enough if you want to censor stuff properly. This is because not all naughty words are four letters long. There are also some not-naughty words that are four letters long [eg: 'four','long','want','this','help']

```
def do_stuff_to_censor_line(line):
    list_of_naughty_words = ['naughty_word_1','naughty_word_2','etc']
    for naughty_word in list_of_naughty_words:
        line.replace(naughty_word,'*$#@!')
    return line
```

I'll leave it up to you to deal with different capitalizations...

Comment: I'm not looking to censor bad words, just any word with 4 letters in a file.